# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not allowed on $.ajax call

Tags: ajax, json, callback, jsonp, cors

I'm trying to load this public API:

https://api.paris.fr:3000/data/1.1/QueFaire/get_geo_activities/?token=3fc939c673e62e7a161ef036699c0a22bc1eed9f076da6236eaca89ab6ef4521&created=0&lat=48.8742&lon=2.3470&radius=1000&offset=0&limit=30 using $.ajax() and I get the following error:

```
Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How can I do this without using JSONP? `api.paris.fr` does not accept the ?callback=?

Also since since api.paris.fr is not mine, how can I do this without a `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`?

Comment: By the way, I can't access that link.

Comment: The link works for me.

Comment: I see it now, going via a VPN. Please ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://api.paris.fr` the browser won't let you do that. As a workaround you could use a proxy. Make a PHP script (or similar) that fetches the JSON from the original source and outputs it.

**apiproxy.php**

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("https://api.paris.fr:3000/data/1.1/QueFaire/get_geo_activities/?token=3fc939c673e62e7a161ef036699c0a22bc1eed9f076da6236eaca89ab6ef4521&created=0&lat=48.8742&lon=2.3470&radius=1000&offset=0&limit=30");
```

**jQuery**

```
$.get("http://yourserver.com/apiproxy.php", function(data) {
    // use data
})
```

Comment: Thanks @hein-andre-gronnestad it worked. I've added `header('Content-type: text/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` as well to the proxy before the echo()

Comment: @RaduChiriac That should do the trick. You should use `Content-Type: application/json` though.

Answer (score -1):

You can try $.ajax({crossDomain:true}). Not sure it helps.